# How do you stop boosted exp for traded pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-series

So I got the torchic gift in pokemon x and y, and he has boosted exp (I'm assuming that this is because he's considered "traded").  Is there any way I can make him gain exp at a normal rate?

Comment: Why do you want the Torchic to gain a normal rate of XP?

Comment: If you are so worried about the growth rate, just battle low leveled Pokemon from Route 2?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the Pokemon is considered 'traded' if the Trainer Name/Trainer ID & Secret ID does not match your own.

- You can breed it with a Ditto by placing both Pokemon into the daycare, collecting & hatching the resulting Egg, and instead raise the child (which will have your Trainer values). Unfortunately it is male - if it were female you could breed it with any Pokemon in the [Field](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Field_%28Egg_Group%29) Egg group.
- Otherwise, you could try restarting the game countless times in order to try and randomly get the correct Trainer ID, although the odds of getting the exact values is like trying to win the lottery. I don't recommend you try this.

Comment: You also need the same Trainer Name. While you point that out at the start, it's not clear at the end. Also it's a 1 in 65536 chance, so it's a much higher chance than lottery^^ Or so I think... You can rename it if only your TID matches at least, so I'd assume this also applies to boosted Exp.

Answer (score 2):

Do what I did if you're worried about an over powered first run: save it for post-game and shut off exp share.  Victory Road and E4 do spike in difficulty; fair warning.

Comment: Even still, the spike isn't that much. I alternated between using EXP Share and not, and had a 'hot-swap' team of about 15 Pokemon that I would swap in and out depending on where I was/what I was doing, and Victory road wild Pokemon were *still* about 4 levels under my Pokemon's level at the time.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not.  (Theoretically, it might gain XP normally if you managed to start a game with the same name, Trainer ID, and secret Trainer ID as the Torchic's OT, but the odds of getting the last two variables to align are 1 out of 4294967296, and even then there might be some flag that still makes the game treat it like an outsider.)

Comment: For renaming purposes, only the Name and TID matter. I'd assume this also applies to boosted Exp. Points.